# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax for coding a new database

Tags: mysql, sql

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 5

The code is:

```
CREATE TABLE click_count (
     id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     page_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     page_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma before the closing parenthesis:

```
CREATE TABLE click_count (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    page_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    page_count INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```